# Drawing Bezier curves using De Casteljau Algorithm in C++ , OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to find the way to generate bezier curve using de casteljau algorithm for one of my assignment here. I am able to generate bezier curve using normal method but unable to start on generating using the above algorithm. It will be of great help if someone can suggest me to right direction or share any piece of code you have. I am not just asking as is. I worked a lot on it and wrote the following code myself to generate the curve. 
I found a web applet which does exactly i needed. (http://www2.mat.dtu.dk/people/J.Gravesen/cagd/decast.html). suggest me how to achieve that

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
#include <stdlib.h>
//using std::exit;
#include <GL/glut.h> // GLUT stuff, includes OpenGL headers as well 
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gl/Gl.h>
#include <gl/Glu.h>


int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
// Keep track of times clicked, on 3 clicks draw.
int NUMPOINTS = 0;

// Point class to keep it a little cleaner.
class Point {
public:
    float x, y, z;
    void setxy(float x2, float y2) { x = x2; y = y2; }
    const Point & operator=(const Point &rPoint) {
         x = rPoint.x;
         y = rPoint.y;
         z = rPoint.z;

         return *this;
      }

};

Point abc[4];

void myInit() {
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glPointSize(4.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,640.0,0.0,480.0);

}

void drawDot(int x, int y) {
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
     glVertex2i(x,y);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void drawLine(Point p1, Point p2) {
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
      glVertex3f(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z);
      glVertex3f(p2.x, p2.y, p2.z);

    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

// Calculate the next bezier point.
Point drawBezier(Point A, Point B, Point C, Point D, double t) {
    Point P;




    P.x = pow((1 - t), 3) * A.x + 3 * t * pow((1 -t), 2) * B.x + 3 * (1-t) * pow(t, 2)* C.x + pow (t, 3)* D.x;
    P.y = pow((1 - t), 3) * A.y + 3 * t * pow((1 -t), 2) * B.y + 3 * (1-t) * pow(t, 2)* C.y + pow (t, 3)* D.y;
    P.z = pow((1 - t), 3) * A.z + 3 * t * pow((1 -t), 2) * B.z + 3 * (1-t) * pow(t, 2)* C.z + pow (t, 3)* D.z;

    return P;
}

void myMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
  // If left button was clicked
  if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
      // Store where the user clicked, note Y is backwards.
    abc[NUMPOINTS].setxy((float)x,(float)(SCREEN_HEIGHT - y));
    NUMPOINTS++;

    // Draw the red  dot.
    drawDot(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);

    // If 3 points are drawn do the curve.
    if(NUMPOINTS == 4) {
        glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
        // Draw two legs of the triangle
        drawLine(abc[0], abc[1]);
        drawLine(abc[1], abc[2]);
        drawLine(abc[2], abc[3]);
        //drawLine(abc[3], abc[4]);
        Point POld = abc[0];
        /* Draw each segment of the curve.  Make t increment in
                   smaller amounts for a more detailed curve. */
        for(double t = 0.0;t <= 1.0; t += 0.1) {
            Point P = drawBezier(abc[0], abc[1], abc[2], abc[3],  t);
            drawLine(POld, P);
            POld = P;
        }
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
        NUMPOINTS = 0;
    }
  }
}

void myDisplay() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,150);
    glutCreateWindow("Bezier Curve");

    glutMouseFunc(myMouse);
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);

    myInit();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing with your curve generation? Maybe you want to share some output results from a particular set of input values and compare it with the results from the applet? 
Or maybe you want a GUI similar to the applet?

Answer (score 4):

works for me, what is the problem?
[image]

I wouldn't post this as an answer, but I can't post an image in a comment

Comment: This is not an implemetaion of De Casteljau's algorithm. this is Bernstein polynomial implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Following [this link](http://raksy.dyndns.org/bezier.html) you can find an interactive javascript implementation.

[image]

Just note how point `AB` is for example computed using `((1-t)*A + t*B)` and see how other points (`BC`, `CD`, `ABC`, `BCD` and finally `ABCD`) are similarly computed.

You can drag `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` and the point `AB` to see how the construction works depending on the parameter `t`.